# Disabling Rails SQL query caching globally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Is there any way to turn off Rails' SQL query caching globally? Or, at the very least, not use it when i enter a transaction block?

Also, does sql query caching only apply to controller actions, or also to rake tasks or background daemons that i write that include Rails and use my models?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Rails 5 we can disable active record query cache using the given function as a middleware.

In application_controller.rb add the given code.

```
around_action :disable_query_cache

def disable_query_cache
    ActiveRecord::Base.uncached do
       yield
    end
end
```

Comment: This did not work for me so I did 

```
    around_action :disable_query_cache

    def disable_active_record_query_cache
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disable_query_cache!
        yield
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.enable_query_cache!
    end
```

Answer (score 18):

Got it! In application.rb:

```
config.middleware.delete ActiveRecord::QueryCache
```

Comment: @PavelEvstigneev have you found a way to accomplish this in Rails 5?

Comment: I did needed it for some bechmars and I just cleared it once per iteration with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.clear_query_cache`