# How do you disable the query cache in rails 4.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

How do you disable the query cache in rails 4.x? It appears that wrapping my queries in model.uncached {} does not stop the query cache. Is there another setting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling Rails SQL query caching globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366262/disabling-rails-sql-query-caching-globally)

Answer (score 8):

Ah, it appears the answer is to add the following to your application.rb

```
config.middleware.delete "ActiveRecord::QueryCache"
```

Comment: have you found any better solution? Don't wanna disable all the cache, just on certain blocks of code.

Comment: Wrapping my queries in Rails 4.1.1 works fine. I did `User.uncached do User.find(1) end`. Have you tried it recently like that?